# Error al descargar fichero que tengo en wp-content/uploads/carpeta

Tags: php, wordpress

Hola estoy intentando descargarme un fichero previamente subido pero al descargarlo me sale un error, y la ruta es la correcta, por si alguien puede darme alguna ayuda.

La ruta que le paso es la correcta, pero no sé porque me dice que error..

**Codigo PHP**

```
  <?php
      global $wp_filesystem;
      WP_Filesystem();
      // directorio donde se realiza la busqueda
      $ruta_2 = $wp_filesystem->wp_content_dir() . "uploads/archivos-subidos/$username/";
        // <!-- Modal content -->
        echo "<i id='myBtn' class='fa fa-eye' aria-hidden='true'>";
        echo "<div id='myModal' class='modal'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
        echo "<span class='close'>&times;</span>";

      function listarArchivos( $path ){
            $dir = opendir($path);
            while ($elemento = readdir($dir)){
            if( $elemento != "." && $elemento != ".."){
            if( is_dir($path.$elemento) ){
              echo "<p><strong>CARPETA: ". $elemento ."</strong></p>";
            } else {
              $ruta_descarga= $path."".$elemento;
              $file_name = basename($ruta_descarga);
              echo $ruta_descarga;
              $filepath=$ruta_descarga;
              $filename=$elemento;
              echo "<a href='$path".str_replace(' ', '%20', $elemento)."' download=''>Descargar PDF de $elemento </a> <br>";
            }
          }
        }
      }
        listarArchivos($ruta_2);
        echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes un problema en la ruta. Estás utilizando la función "wp_content_dir()" para averiguar la ruta al directorio del wp-content de wordpress y así examinar el directorio que tú quieres. Esto es correcto, pero no para poner el enlace en el link al archivo, ya que este tiene que ser una url y no un directorio del servidor. Te dejo el código modificado que lo que hace es quitar el "wp_content_dir()" de la ruta del enlace y ponerle el "content_url()" que es lo que tiene que tener.

```
  <?php
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
  global $wp_filesystem;
  WP_Filesystem();
  // directorio donde se realiza la busqueda
  $ruta_2 = $wp_filesystem->wp_content_dir() . "uploads/documentos/";
    // <!-- Modal content -->
    echo "<i id='myBtn' class='fa fa-eye' aria-hidden='true'>";
    echo "<div id='myModal' class='modal'>";
    echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
    echo "<span class='close'>&times;</span>";

  function listarArchivos( $path ){
        global $wp_filesystem;          
        $ruta_2 = explode($wp_filesystem->wp_content_dir(), $path);
        $dir = opendir($path);
        while ($elemento = readdir($dir)){
        if( $elemento != "." && $elemento != ".."){
        if( is_dir($path.$elemento) ){
          echo "<p><strong>CARPETA: ". $elemento ."</strong></p>";
        } else {
          $ruta_descarga= $path."".$elemento;
          $file_name = basename($ruta_descarga);
          echo $ruta_descarga;
          $filepath=$ruta_descarga;
          $filename=$elemento;
          $url_path = content_url()."/".$ruta_2[1].str_replace(' ', '%20', $elemento);
          echo "<a href='$url_path' download=''>Descargar PDF de $elemento </a> <br>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
    listarArchivos($ruta_2);
    echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
?>
```

Nota: He añadido al principio el "require_once" porque a veces si no estás en el sitio de administración, la función WP_Filesystem(); suele dar error.